# problem using foreach in linq query result

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have linq query as follows:

```
var result = (from Customer cust in db select new { userNameList = cust.UserName }).ToList();
```

i want to loop through each value in the list<>

I tried to use the foreach to accomplish this. It is stupid i could not figure it out

I'm using something like this

```
foreach (List<string> item in result)
            {
                if (item.ToString() == userName)
                {
                    userExistsFlag = 1;
                }
            }
```

But the .net compiler is just freaking out:

and giving me these errors

1. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
2. Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Thanks in anticipation

**OF ALL THESE IMPLEMENTATIONS WHICH ONE IS MOST EFFICIENT AND CONSUMES LESS RESOURCES.
IT WOULD BE KIND ENOUGH IF SOME ONE CAN CLARIFY THIS FOR ME.**

Comment: of what type is `db` in the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shorter using Linq:

```
bool userExistsFlag  = result.Any( x=> x.userNameList  == userName);
```

As suggested in the other answers you do not need to project to an anonymous type:

```
var userNames = (from Customer cust in db select cust.UserName).ToList();
bool userExists = userNames.Contains(userName);
```

**Edit:**

The most efficient - if you do not need the set of user names otherwise - is to query the DB directly to check whether the user name exists, so

```
 bool userExists = db.Any( x => x.UserName == userName);
```

Credit goes to @Chris Shaffer in the comments and @Cybernatet's answer - he was almost there. I would suggest you accept his answer but use Any() ;-)

Comment: +1 - Most efficient method `bool userExistsFlag = db.Any(x => x.UserName == userName)` (which you almost have in there :) ).

Comment: how could this work? db.Any(x => x.UserName == userName) ... wouldnt 'db' have more then one tables? .. EDIT: never mind.. 'db' is just the customer table.. i took things literally :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var result = (from Customer cust in db select new { userNameList = cust.UserName }).ToList();
userExistsFlag = result.Where(a=> a.userNameList == userName).Count() > 0;

or

userExistsFlag = (
                    from Customer cust in db 
                    where cust.UserName = userName
                    select cust
                 ).Count() > 0;
```

Comment: shouldn't that be cust.UserName == userName

Comment: -1 - .Count() > 0 should not be used to detect presence - that is what .Any() is for.

Answer (score 2):

If your query returns a list of names, your FOREACH loop should look like this

```
foreach( String name in results ){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip using `new { userNameList = cust.UserName }` which is making it an anonymous instance. You can try

```
var result = (from Customer cust in db select cust.UserName ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're just getting the one property and want a list of strings there is no reason to use an anonymous type.  code should work like this:

```
var result = (from Customer cust in db select cust.UserName).ToList();
```